# Start exe as child of explorer.exe

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to start an exe file (not from me) which need to be a child process of explorer.exe to run fine.

If I use `os.startfile` or `win32api.Shellexecute` it doesn't work fine.

I found this : http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_from_process.html

With running :

```
from win32api import ShellExecute

RFPexp = r"D:\RunFromProcess-x64.exe"
myFilePath = "path\to\myfile.exe"

args = "nomsg explorer.exe %s" %myFilePath
ShellExecute(0,'Open', RFPexp, args, None, 1)
```

Then `myfile.exe` is a child process of explorer.exe and all works well.

The problem is that it relies on this utility, which I dunno if it will be maintain, stays free, keep compatible with windows in the future, etc etc

So how could I do that with python itself ?

Thanks

Comment: you should read the doc to show you have try almost something otherwise I'm afraid you will never have any positive answer

Comment: FoxMaSk, I've tried all I could ... that's why I ask here  win32api.WinExec, os.startfile, subprocess.call, subprocess.Popen with creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS, nothing works.

Comment: from what you explained, there are too many unknowns to use this tools to build a stable solution. Does the person who provides you `myfile.exe` cant help and tell you how he launches myfile on his side ?

Comment: This file is intended to be launched by the user, clicking an icon. The problem is I launch it on different machines with a python app client listening some udp message, and starting it. But then it is a child of my app and not of explorer.exe. The file itself is the server for Autodesk BackBurner. And having help from autodesk is...well... impossible ?

Comment: look at this tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autodesk to see if its related to your own post and then add it ; may be you will find more help

Comment: Still can't manage to do it. Looking at msdn (wmi) etc but I may not be high end enough for this. Any help would be appreciated.